# How to force maven to register all needed avros schemas in Kafka Schema Registry?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, schema, avro

I have **Batch ** schema which **contains List of other schemas**. Those schemas are declared in other schema files so when I publish Batch to Kafka Schema registry registering only Batch schema ingoring all implicit one's.

Is there any way to force Kafka Schema Registry to register all avro schemas. I know I can use API but for is better to use in-jar solutions like Maven.

I've tried to find solutions in Web but nothing. I am not sure if it even possible without declaring inner schemas in Batch schema.